# Get Eticket and segment from PNR

Tags: soap, sabre

When I get PNR from consolidator, I want to use API to get eticket and segment.
Please advise API to do that
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Retrieve Itinerary** (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Retrieve_Itinerary). It gives you the ticket number/s, corresponding segments and also refrences in case you price EMD-A to those tickets